How to solve: libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR Invalid IHDR data
Inputting this code:
BurnesCutterHeat <- colorRampPalette(paletteer::paletteer_d("RColorBrewer::RdBu", n = 9, direction = -1))(16)


BurnesPitches %>% 
  filter(pitch_name == "Cutter" & !is.na(plate_x) & !is.na(plate_z) & is.finite(plate_x) & is.finite(plate_z)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = plate_x, y = plate_z)) +
  stat_density2d_filled() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(BurnesCutterHeat), aesthetics = c("fill", "color"))

Receiving this error:
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_path, x$x, x$y, index, switch(x$rule, winding = 1L,  : 
  non-finite x or y in graphics path
In addition: Warning message:
In grid.newpage() : agg could not write to the given file

Once I received the error saying "non-finite x or y in graphics path" I added in the code to exclude NA values and only include finite values in the filter of the ggplot. Still receiving the same error, cannot find the solution. I have used this exact code and got the data from the exact same source many times before and have never encountered this.
> dput(head(BurnesPitches, 25))
structure(list(pitch_name = c("Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", 
"Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", 
"Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", 
"Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", 
"Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup", "Changeup"), player_name = c("Burnes, Corbin", 
"Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", 
"Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", 
"Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", 
"Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", 
"Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", 
"Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin", "Burnes, Corbin"
), release_speed = c(88.9, 87.8, 91.5, 89.3, 89.5, 89.5, 87.2, 
88, 88.9, 89.2, 88.5, 89, 88, 89.7, 89.5, 89.7, 89.6, 88.6, 88.3, 
89.9, 89.8, 90.6, 90.4, 90.3, 89.9), release_spin_rate = c(2060L, 
1831L, 2092L, 1986L, 2117L, 2044L, 1906L, 2002L, 2000L, 2090L, 
2115L, 2119L, 1938L, 1978L, 2056L, 1904L, 1922L, 1839L, 1725L, 
1878L, 1958L, 2015L, 2081L, 2018L, 2089L), release_pos_x = c(-0.99, 
-1.16, -1.13, -1.03, -1.08, -1.14, -1.24, -1.13, -1.09, -1.16, 
-1.07, -1, -1.16, -1.13, -1.18, -1.12, -1.27, -1.25, -1.35, -1.2, 
-1.22, -1.27, -1.23, -1.19, -1.18), release_pos_z = c(5.62, 5.57, 
5.63, 5.59, 5.66, 5.61, 5.53, 5.61, 5.72, 5.72, 5.78, 5.71, 5.82, 
5.72, 5.66, 5.85, 5.57, 5.54, 5.57, 5.5, 5.59, 5.69, 5.68, 5.6, 
5.62), HorizMovement = c(14.64, 10.32, 12.36, 11.76, 12.84, 10.32, 
15, 16.2, 9.12, 16.56, 12.6, 16.44, 17.4, 9.84, 10.32, 10.8, 
15, 13.92, 14.64, 15.12, 15.84, 16.8, 15.72, 14.64, 15.6), VertMovement = c(10.92, 
6.84, 6.96, 8.28, 9.6, 10.8, 8.64, 0.84, 11.76, 7.68, 11.88, 
6.48, 6.6, 9.24, 5.52, 6.96, 8.28, 5.88, 4.68, 5.64, 5.76, 3.72, 
3.24, 3.12, 5.76), plate_x = c(-0.28, -0.93, -0.09, -0.8, -0.39, 
-0.12, -2, -1.21, -0.51, -0.83, 0.17, 0.48, -0.29, -0.33, -0.99, 
-1.37, -1.34, -0.08, 0.03, 0.78, -0.71, -0.53, -1.2, 0.22, -0.18
), plate_z = c(2.18, 2.54, 1.96, 2.9, 2.79, 0.62, 2.43, 1.89, 
3.88, 2.04, 2.41, 0.71, 1.18, 1.92, 2.73, 2.56, 2.09, 1.75, 0.87, 
0.86, 1.7, 1.51, 1.34, 1.39, 1.09), `Usage %` = c(11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -25L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001f62a0db0b0>, sorted = "pitch_name")


I'm not getting any errors or warnings when I run your code. I get quite a nice heatmap if I omit the filter. I suspect somewhere in your real data, which wasn't included in your dput, there is some strange values

@Edward That is so odd, I tried doing the same thing and only plotting the dput data and am still getting the same error. Don't know if it is a hardware issue or what, but now I cant plot any data.
